# Get Base64 ImageData in Cordova, upload it in a mysql Database and display it in Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I would like to take a Picture with Cordova and upload it with this Code:

```
  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
  $httpBackend.whenGET('').passThrough();
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  var lol = imageData;
  alert(lol);
     $http.get('http://localhost/addpicture.php' + "?User="+ Auth.getUser().username + "&Image=" +  lol).then(function (response){
    if(response.data == "New record created successfully"){

    }
    else{
      alert('There was a Connection-Error');
    }
  })

}, function(err) {
  // error
});    }, false);

}
```

When I display it directly it works:

```
  <img  ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
```

But when I load the the Base64 from the Database and try to display it like this:

```
 $http.get('http://localhost/Ionic/img.php' ).then(function (response2){
var imagebody = "";
for( var key in response2.data){
  console.log('lol');
  imagebody += '<li> <a> <img ng-src="{{data:image/jpeg;base64,'   + response2.data[Object.keys(response2.data)[key]].ImageURL + '}}"> </a> </li>';


 }   


    document.getElementById("pixx").innerHTML = imagebody;
         });
```

It does not work anymore. It is the same Base64 Code. I also tried it with "src=" and "data-ng-src=". In the Database the Base64 is in a VARCHAR-Column with 10000 Characters allowed.

Why the image does not display?

Thank you for your help!
Regards

Comment: You can not send base64 into queryString. Use post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing your img tag this way :

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,response2.data[Object.keys(response2.data)[key]].ImageURL" data-err-src="images/jpeg/name.jpeg">
```

assuming **response2.data[Object.keys(response2.data)[key]].ImageURL** contains the image in base64.